# Redirect users to a new page after logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am brand new to C#/.Net. I am trying to create a login page that directs admins to one page of the site and all other users to another. I have successfully added the required pages via aspnet_regsql.exe, am able to get data from the database and created users and folder permissions via the ASP.NET configuration back end website. When I made the user I checked the SQL server database and it is working but when I try to login nothing happens. I did some research and realized I need to add code to this method to get it to forward to the right page but I don't know where to start.

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)

{
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the input on redirecting. How do you validate the login with the database? I am using the standard tables that go with the login control.

Comment: There are so many questions here that I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must authenticate the user and then you redirect user to page that's available for him.

```
If (authentication success) 
{ 
// iF you want to parse user id of the user to the page then you can use query string 
// like this " ~/home.page?id=129" 

Response.Redirect("~/Home.page") 
}
```

If you use a custom data table, then you can write a procedure to authenticate the user, 
I use a custom data table to hold members and I validate using an SQL procedure, as shown below:

```
 Create Procedure [dbo].[Authenticate]
    (
    @Email varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(50)    
    ) 
    As

    Declare @@ID int 


    Set @@ID = (select ID from users where Email = @Email)

    if exists (select * from [dbo].[Users] where Email = @Email and [Password] = @Password ) 
    select 'True' as IsValid , @@ID as ID
    else 
    select 'False' as Isvalid , 0 as ID

    return
```

Answer (score 2):

Response.Redirect() should help you on your way

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the membership provider:

```
if (Membership.GetUser() != null && Page.User.IsInRole("administrator"))
{
   //admin user
   Response.Redirect("adminarea.html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)

{

// Validate From DB
//After successful Validation

Response.Redirect("Your Page name");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input on redirecting. How do you validate the login with the database? I am using the standard tables that go with the login control.